# Connect STM32 Ethernet to PHY - clock signal

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, clock, ethernet

I want to connect MAC available on [STM32F745](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/96/ed/61/9b/e0/6c/45/0b/DM00166116.pdf/files/DM00166116.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00166116.pdf) to [KSZ8041FTL](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ksz8041tl-ftl-mll.pdf) (PHY) via RMII.

I will clock PHY from external 50MHz clock generator, connecting clock to the *REFCLK* input of PHY.

But what about STM32? **Should I also connect 50 MHz clock to the STM32?** If yes then I guess I should connect it to the *RMII_REF_CLK* input (PA1)?

Can I just connect output of the clock generator to both IC?

Comment: Yes.. In RMII mode, you have to provide same clock to both Micro and PHY Chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the datasheets you provided, if you want to use RMII mode there seems to be no other alternative than what you already suggested.
Namely, you must connect 50 MHz clock output **both to PHY (REFCLK) and MAC (RMII_REF_CLK)** in order to synchronize them.